# .Net Lumisoft audio microphone over the network

Tags: .net, stream, lumisoft

I made a program in C # to send the microphone through internet. I used the library Lumisoft that returns encoded G711 stream. I would now like to convert the stream in wav or mp3 codec. How can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

RTP_SendStream of Lumisoft has RTP_Packet and rtpPacket.data is byte[] which can be written to file system with System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes then use NAudio from Nuget to convert to wav